# Pascal ABC Подсчет количества слов в предложениях

Tags: файлы, pascal, текст

в предложениях не более чем  20 слов, определите: сколько в файле имеется предложений, состоящих из одного, двух, трех и т. д. слов.

вопрос заключается в следующем:
подсчет слов в предложении получается, однако не знаю как реализовать подсчет предложений с определенным количеством слов без ввода 20 новых переменных. есть ли альтернативный способ решения данной задачи?

Comment: массив на 20 значений, индекс массива - количество слов в предложении, значение массива - соответственно количество предложений

Comment: покажи код подсчета слов в предложении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оставь максимум одну пробел по порядку в предложении. И убери побелы перед началом.Добавь пробел после предложения чтобы он тоже считался. Потом считай пробелы и сколько пробелов столько слов.
Например:
__Privet_____a__kak___zhe__ty
Privet_a_kak_zhe_ty_
5 слов